# Programmatically creating and setting LinearLayout divider

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` and I want to have 50 pixels of blank space between its child views. After some research I've found that dividers can do this job. I don't want to use XML but create everything programmatically. Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

ColorDrawable divider = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
divider.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 0);             
parent.setDividerDrawable(divider);
parent.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);

....children are added here to parent...
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. No blank space appears between the children.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong there?

Comment: Can I ask just out of curiosity why you don't want to use XML?

Comment: if it is transparent why would it be visible?

Comment: @meditat: It should be blank space, that's why I use transparent.

Comment: @LieForBananas: It's part of a generic GUI toolkit.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, `ColorDrawable` was the culprit. When using `ShapeDrawable` instead it works fine, i.e. like this:

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

ShapeDrawable divider = new ShapeDrawable();
divider.setIntrinsicWidth(50);
divider.setAlpha(0);             
parent.setDividerDrawable(divider);
parent.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
```